# How to set up a FTP server

Tags: internet, raid, ftp

I am in need of creating an FTP server that can be accessed across the internet; with a bunch of space. I currently have a computer that I'm considering using, though, if it is not deemed to be good enough for use, I'll buy a new computer specifically for this purpose. Problem is, though, I do not know anything about how to set up an FTP server, or for that matter, what is required in a system to do this.

The computer that I was considering using is an HP Desktop computer with 3 GB loaded, Windows XP Home media edition, 200 GB Internal storage (would be upgraded with a RAID 0 array of 6x IDE drives of varying size), 620 watt PSU, 240 MB (i think) NVidia onboard GPU (also probably would be upgraded), and a Quad Core AMD 64bit processor (Forget exact model). I would likely upgrade the Operating System to Windows 7, provided that it would be the most efficient in creating an FTP Server.

I have an HP Procurve 4000M Ethernet switch (http://community.moertel.com/~thor/pix/20051111-procurve/img_0856-wm.jpg) which I will likely use to connect the FTP Server computer to my home network as well as the internet. Keep in mind Im not entirely sure that I will be using this switch, as despite the device being operable, it requires a lot of power and also emits a lot of noise due to the massive fan array within the device, and im not sure the others living in my house would appreciate the noise 24/7.

The main purpose of the FTP server will be to share files with the members of my company- We are an indie game development group. So far, we have been using Google Drive and Dropbox for our files, but the need for an FTP server arised when A) we ran out of space that we could afford on Google Drive, and also that B) none of the online drive and paid FTP services provided enough preferences for us. The files that will be stored on the server will vary from small .TXT Documents to extremely large .C4D files and other extremely large file types (such as photoshop .PSB files, Texture libraries, etc.). keep in mind that the people who will be accessing this server will mostly be accessing it from over the internet.

I have a massive ammount of knowlege on how to build computers, installing Operating Systems, etc. so I can do nearly all things that may be required to set up this FTP server.

Comment: *"I have a massive ammount of knowlege on how to build computers, installing Operating Systems, etc."* But you fail to realize that most implementations of [RAID 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#RAID_0) requires drives of the same size, or rather, fix the size of the array to the number of drives multiplied by the size of the smallest drive. PATA drives are starting to be hard to come by. RAID 0 has no redundancy; any one failed drive will render the entire array unreadable. And of course, XP being ancient these days; a fresh install is always cleaner than an upgrade. ...

Comment: I had previously known about the redundancy issue and was willing to take that risk; however if all of the drives in the array require to be the same size then im screwed in that respect.

Comment: I was not planning on doing an actual upgrade either; If I mentioned upgrade I meant fresh install from my OEM disc.

Comment: Not all the **drives** in a RAID array need to be the same size, but usually all the **partitions** you are building the RAID from need to be. E.g. if you have a 2TB and a 3TB drive, then you can create a 2 disk RAID from those using 2TB from each drive. (The remaining 1TB on the large disk will either be unused or you can create another disk from that. Either a plain volume of part of another mdadm RAID.) - Note that not every RAID method supports this.

Answer (score 5):

1. Please do not use XP. XP is nearly out of support and you would need to ditch it in less than a year. (win7, a free Linux distribution, a BSD, windows server, ... all are fine. Just do not use XP.)
2. I hope you realise that FTP is not secure. Unless everybody can download anonymously please consider something else (e.g. sFTP, notice the s)
3. No GPU is needed for an FTP server. Why leave it in these continuously using power?
4. How good is your home internet? Both download and **upload**. (With DSK or cable upload is often extremely slow).
5. How are backups done. Are they stored off-site?

...

I could go on, but you are looking for a file server setup in an office and trying to do so with an ancient OS, on an unsuitable desktop, probably connected to a non business network. Running into problems is likely.

I understand that Indy game dev. might not have all the resources of the big firms, but hiring someone to do this for you might be quite cost effective in the long run.

Comment: +1 for realism. I think OP needs to take a couple steps back and look for other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Well I actually agree with all the answers already given (especially not using XP - even MS say that it's security is bad) I would just like to add an alternative solution for your consideration.

You can pick up a Raspberry PI cheap, hook up a decent powered USB hub and plug in externally powered drives.  Easily configure Raspbian to host an ftp server (or sftp which would be better) and you are set.  Low power consumption and if you need more space you just plug in another drive and create symbolic links so it looks like one drive.

You do not need a decent machine to host FTP, the machine is there to authenticate, then it's mostly about line speed.

From your post it seems that you are more familiar with Windows than Linux but to set up something as simple as an ftp server in Linux is easy, what's more is that you can change the ftp port to 80 so that you get the least throttling from your ISP (and trust me, everyone gets throttled, no matter what your ISP advertises).

Comment: +1 for the idea of moving to port 80 when using a consumer line. (Business lines do not need to work around). Power use and noice will still not be low. The rPi might not use much, but an decent RAID array of a dozen drives will.

Answer (score 1):

What **Hennes** is 100% correct, it's never a good idea to use your PC as a server.

If you really really don't have the money to buy a hosting plan, then consider using [000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com/), or some other [free hosting service](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-7-easy-and-free-web-hosting-services/), those hosting services are not good, but you get what you pay for, and you're not paying anything.

Register a [.tk domain](http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en), which's also free, and there are many [free domain name providers](http://www.prchecker.info/web-hosting/best-free-domain-name-services/). Setup everything and you're ready to go.

In case you would want to setup your own server and install ftp server, here's [how to install proftpd on centos](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-installing-configuring-proftpd-ftp-server.html), you may need to follow another tutorial depending on your OS.

I never use FTP, it's not secure and securing it gives me headache, why bother configuring it when i can just use [SFTP](https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/880/Using+FileZilla+for+FTP%7B47%7DSFTP#gs)?